# How do you reverse the playback of AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, audio, avfoundation

Basically in my app I record a sound, and play it back, I would like to reverse the playback of this audio.
I've checked around on the net and I can't seem to find the answer.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently not supported by the AVAudioPlayer. You have to implement your own player to archive reverse playback.

There is a [answer on the Apple mailing list on this topic](http://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2011/Apr/msg00071.html). Short Version: rollout your own or use a 3rd party plugin like the [DIRAC Plugin](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html).

Comment: I see, so how would I do that?

Comment: Are there any simpler solutions?